# XSLT conditional test with absolute value

Tags: xml, firefox, math, xslt, xpath

I'm trying to figure out how to make a test in my xsl transformation using absolute values.
Something like this:

`<xsl:when test="abs(/root/values/mean) &lt; /root/thresholds/min">`

```
   <xsl:attribute name="style">background-color:red;</xsl:attribute>
```

`</xsl:when>`

Is that possible. I've tried using templates, but it seemed the wrong path. Moving to XSLT 2.0 did not work for me either (I guess Firefox 3.6 do not support it).

Any thoughts?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a general, short and easy  XPath expression that returns the absolute value for any number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolute as in non-negative? Define a variable that is conditional.

```
<xsl:variable name="abs">
   <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test="/root/values/mean &lt; 0><xsl:value-of select="-1 * /root/values/mean" /></xsl:when>
       <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="/root/values/mean" /></xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:when test="$abs">
   <xsl:attribute name="style">background-color:red;</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:when>
```

Comment: You just forgot the the closing otherwise tag. Besides this fact it solved my problem. many tks

Answer (score 3):

**Generally, in XPath 1.0 (XSLT 1.0) you can find the absolute value of a number `$vNum`** with the following XPath expression:

```
$vNum*($vNum > 0) -$vNum*not($vNum > 0)
```

**In XPath 2.0 (XSLT 2.0) one uses the standard function [abs()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-abs)**

Answer (score 1):

Another way to find the absolute value of a number in XPath 1.0 is

```
number(translate(string($X), '-', ''))
```

Comment: This is an amazingly simple and effective technique.